# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'field' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code

```
 var allVals = [];
function attachedchanged(e) {

    var grid = $(e).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    allVals.push(selectedItem);
}

function onSaveClick() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Asset/SaveAssociate',
        data: { value:allVals },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.read();
        }
    })
}
```

am getting this error onsaveclick()
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'field' of undefined or null reference

AT here in kendo.all.min.js error @
{i.trigger(vt,{field:e.field,node:e.node,index:e.index,items:e.items||[this],action:e.node?e.action||"itemchange":"itemchange"})

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `e` variable doesn't set to any value. It's `undefined`, so when you try to dereference `e.field` you get the error.

Look what do you receive from ajax in `data` object.